# Shiny Server R sessions creates a tempdir() it doesn't have permission to access

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny app that works as expected both locally and when containerized. The app receives some user input, queries a database, and returns a `.zip` containing a `.pdf` and `.xlsx` file. Because reasons, I will be deploying it to a server running Shiny Server. When running the app, I get an error that processing the `[filename].knit.md` is impossible because "Permission denied:"

[image]

After digging into why this might be the case, I think it's a function of the user `shiny` (running the app in `shiny-server.conf`) doesn't have permissions to access the dir/file. The trouble I'm having is diagnosing this error because the temp dir and file don't appear to exist anywhere in the local directory structure.

In `server.R`, I call `tempfile()` and use that temporary file as the input for `output_file` in the `render()` command. I know that `tempfile()` is a subdirectory of the per-session temporary directory so how can I ensure that user `shiny` can access any `tempdir()` created during app operation?

Further, am I assuming correctly that the temp dir in the image above is automatically deleted when the app errors out? I can't find that dir anywhere in the `/tmp` tree of the server.

Answer (score 2):

In the doc of `tempdir()`

> By default, tmpdir will be the directory given by tempdir(). This will be a subdirectory of the per-session temporary directory found by the following rule when the R session is started. The environment variables TMPDIR, TMP and TEMP are checked in turn and the first found which points to a writable directory is used: if none succeeds ‘/tmp’ is used. The path should not contain spaces. Note that setting any of these environment variables in the R session has no effect on tempdir(): the per-session temporary directory is created before the interpreter is started.

So

```
mkdir mydir
export TMPDIR=mydir
Rscript -e "tempfile();tempdir();"
```

give

```
[1] "mydir/RtmphR2Rkx/file19da392dac5546"
[1] "mydir/RtmphR2Rkx"
```

Else give the right to /tmp